# Can I return a non-partitioned table with function mr?

Tags: sql, mapreduce, dolphindb

I wrote the code below to return a table t using function `mr`.

```
t = mr(ds, main{, day}, , unionAll);
```

But joining table t with an in-memory table raises an error requiring both tables to be non-partitioned. Any efficient way to convert t to be non-partitioned?

Answer (score 0):

The final function you used for `mr` is `unionAll`. Check its syntax unionAll(tables, [partition=true], [byColName=false]) and you can modify the parameter partition. If partition is set to “false”, the result is an non-partitioned in-memory table; if partition is set to “true”, the result is a partitioned in-memory table with sequential domain. The default value is “true”. So you can set partition to false to return a non-partitioned table is:

```
mrRst3 = mr(sqlDS(<select * from pt where tradedate between 20200102:20200110>),mapData,unionAll{,,false})
```